# cordova-plugin-inappbrowser not working from angular

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova

im trying to open pdf a file received via api from angular cordova application.

```
this.laccountservice.downloadPDF(order).subscribe(
      (res) => {
      var files=  new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' })
        console.log(files)
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(files);
      //window.open(fileURL); // if you want to open it in new tab
     cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

how to define cordova? 
import { } from "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" ?. im not using ionic simple angular application using phonegap cordova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cordova instance` the following ways

```
(window as any).cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

**OR**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var cordova:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {

  constructor() {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
  }

}
```

Comment: dear using this i cant open pdf file

Comment: But, your question was *how to declare cordova?*